# How to use a PHP switch statement to check if a string contains a word (but can also contain others)?

Tags: php, string, switch-statement, url-parameters, php-include

I'm using a PHP switch to include certain files based on the incoming keywords passed in a parameter of the page's URL.

The URL, for example, could be: `...page.php?kw=citroen%20berlingo%20keywords`

Inside the page, I'd like to use something like this:

```
<?
    switch($_GET['kw']){

        case "berlingo":     
            include 'berlingo.php'
            break;
        case "c4":
            include 'c4.php';
            break;

    } 
?>
```

What I want to do in the first case is include the `berlingo.php` file if the keyword parameter *contains* `berlingo`, but it doesn't have to be *exactly* that keyword alone.

For example, I want to include the `berlingo.php` file if the keyword is `berlingo`, but *also* if it's `citroen berlingo`.

How can I evaluate if a given string contains a value using a PHP case select (switch statement)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691483/using-strstr-inside-a-switch-php) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691524/2144616), the solutions I've come up with (*while still using a case select*) are below.

You can use either [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) or [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php). The reason I chose to use `stristr()` in this case is simply because it's case-*insensitive*, and thus, is more robust.

**Example:**

```
$linkKW = $_GET['kw'];

switch (true){
   case stristr($linkKW,'berlingo'):
      include 'berlingo.php';
      break;
   case stristr($linkKW,'c4'):
      include 'c4.php';
      break;
}
```

You could also use [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) or [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) if you'd like *(thanks, [Fractaliste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2814253/fractaliste))*, though I personally find this more difficult to read. Same deal as the other method above; I went the case-*insensitive* route.

**Example:**

```
$linkKW = $_GET['kw'];

switch (true){
   case stripos($linkKW,'berlingo') !== false:
      include 'berlingo.php';
      break;
   case stripos($linkKW,'c4') !== false:
      include 'c4.php';
      break;
}
```

Comment: Your idea with `strpos()` : `switch (true) {case strpos($name, 'incident') !== false: /* The job */`

Answer (score 8):

Since in a `switch` statement only a simple equality testing will be performed it won't help you much here. You need to run the string through a string matching function, best suited of which is `strpos`. The straight forward answer is:

```
if (strpos($_GET['kw'], 'berlingo') !== false) {
    include 'berlingo.php';
} else if (strpos($_GET['kw'], 'c4') !== false) {
    include 'c4.php';
} … and so on …
```

The more elegant solution would be something like this:

```
$map = array('berlingo' => 'berlingo.php', 'c4' => 'c4.php', …);
foreach ($map as $keyword => $file) {
    if (strpos($_GET['kw'], $keyword) !== false) {
        include $file;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, if the correspondence between the keyword and the file is always 1:1:

```
$keywords = array('berlingo', 'c4', …);
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    if (strpos($_GET['kw'], $keyword) !== false) {
        include "$keyword.php";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function as:

```
if(strpos($_GET['kw'],'berlingo') !== false) {
 include 'berlingo.php';
}
if(strpos($_GET['kw'],'c4') !== false) {
 include 'c4.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$keywords = array('berlingo', 'c4');
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
  if(strpos($_GET['kw'], $keyword) !== FALSE)
    include("$keyword.php");
```

I wouldn't recommend including php files based on user input though.

Comment: If it's matched against a whitelist as in this case there should be no problem including files based on user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expression in switch -> case:

```
<?php

    $kw = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "kw");

    switch($kw){

        case (preg_match('/*berlingo*/', $kw) ? true : false):     
            include 'berlingo.php';
            break;

        case "c4":
            include 'c4.php';
            break;

    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's a *code smell* if you're including scripts via GET variables, but you can do this elegantly using a value class with methods whose logic return the value object itself if true.

The idea is to keep in mind that a `switch` statement will execute any code where $switch == $case (a loose match). So just create methods which either return `$this`, or nothing at all.

Example:

```
class Haystack {
    public $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function contains($needle):
    {
        if (strpos($this->value, $needle) !== false)
            return $this;
    }
}

$kw = new Haystack($_GET['kw']);

switch ($kw) {
    case $kw->contains('berlingo'):
        require_once 'berlingo.php';
    case $kw->contains('c4'):
        require_once 'c4.php';
}
```

You can, of course, generously garnish this code with typehints. If you do, and are not using a version of PHP which supports nullable return types (ie a method signature of `public function contains(string $substring): ?Haystack`) then your class would have to elaborate to reflect that.

Example:

```
final class Haystack {
    private $value;
    private $isMain;

    public function __construct(string $value, bool $isMain = true)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->isMain = $isMain;
    }

    final public function contains($needle): Haystack
    {
        if (strpos($this->value, $needle) !== false)
            return $this;
        return new Haystack($needle, false);
    }
}
```

This way, if your explicit matching logic fails inside the method, if for some reason `new Haystack($_GET['kw']) == new Haystack($needle);` is true, the non-matching property "$isMain" will ensure they are not evaluated as equal.

Again, I would re-examine why you'd want to do this in the first place for this particular situation; traditionally, [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is a dependency management tool which would be used to include various scripts you need via a PSR autoload standard. That in combination with a Router library would probably be the most useful to address your actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is one for checking if a string contains another string.

There are [other functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) for checking similarity of strings, etc.

A `switch` won't do, though, since it compares static expressions against a single value. You'll have to use `if`s.

Comment: Core Xii could you please provide the correct version of the switch i used in order to do what i want to accomplish? Just tried to rewrite the switch using that strpos() but got error, guess i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is WAY after the fact, but just as an aside, one can always avoid the loop altogether if expecting a 1:1 relationship.

Something along the lines of:

```
$map = array('berlingo' => 'berlingo.php', 'c4' => 'c4.php', …);

if( !isset( $map[$_GET['kw']] ))
    throw new Exception("Blah!!");

include $map[$_GET['kw']];
```

...just sharing as an FYI for newbies.