# Using strstr inside a switch php

Tags: php, switch-statement, strstr

I just cannot think of the code. I have waay too many if statments which I want to change to be a switch statement, but I cannot find of the logic.

At the moment I have:

```
if(strstr($var,'texttosearch'))
   echo 'string contains texttosearch';

if(strstr($var,'texttosearch1'))
   echo 'string contains texttosearch1';

if(strstr($var,'texttosearch2'))
   echo 'string contains texttosearc2h';

//etc etc...
```

But how can I achieve the same within a switch?

Comment: Actually `foreach` solution by `php-coder` is better to use `switch`. it will reduce line of codes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
switch (true) {
  case strstr($var,'texttosearch'):
    echo 'string contains texttosearch';
    break;
  case strstr($var,'texttosearch1'):
    echo 'string contains texttosearch1';
    break;
  case strstr($var,'texttosearch2'):
    echo 'string contains texttosearc2h';
    break;
}
```

Note, that this is slightly different to your own solution, because the `switch`-statement will not test against the other `case`s, if an earlier already matches, but because you use separate `if`s, instead if `if-else` your way always tests against every case.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can't achieve this with `switch` (more elegant than now) because it compare values but you want compare only part of values. Instead you may use loop:

```
$patterns = array('texttosearch', 'texttosearch1', 'texttosearch2');
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (strstr($var, $pattern)) {
        echo "String contains '$pattern'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely +1. Definitely. I'd give you +2 if I could.

Comment: better answer to this case +1, but @KingCrunch snippet is interesting for realize a specific action.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way around:

```
switch(true) {
case strstr($var, "texttosearch"):
    // do stuff
    break;
case strstr($var, "texttosearch1"):
    // do other stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: @William Jones can you pls avoid such words in public, that to tech discussion.